# Controll LED Strip with Arduino BLE

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I'm working on this project where I have interfaced a LED strip (a two wire LED strip) with [this](http://redbearlab.com/blendmicro/) Arduino (its not an Uno). I have setup every thing correctly according to [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/PWM-an-RGB-LED-Strip-with-Arduino/) instructable. I'm able to make a simple blinky pattern and I turn it on/off with an Android app I made to communicate with the Arduino using Bluetooth on my phone. Cool.

What I cannot understand is, since the strip is two wired, how should I address individual LEDs on the strip to make more complex patterns? Can I use bit shifts? Reading an article from Makezine (insufficient reps to post more than 2 links), it says that I should connect the strup directly to the output pin. IMO, this will fry the Arduino or in a less virulent sway, not light up the strip in any way.

Comment: Is [this](http://makezine.com/projects/make-36-boards/android-arduino-led-strip-lights/) the article you mention ? It does say to connect directly only **for 1 or 2 LEDs** and you are right : typical limit is 40mA per Arduino output pin. And it won't work directly if you have common anodes like in the schematic.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing individual LEDS on a simple strip with LEDs in series and/or parallel connection is just not possible. 
Connecting the strip directly to an output pin is completely nonsense. Forget it.

You need a strip with digital LED controllers populated, as described (for instance) in another link mentioned in your second link: http://www.adafruit.com/products/306

Have a look at this, then I'm sure you will come back with more detailed questions ;-)

Comment: Nice ! Have you tried this type of LED strip, I'm very curious about it ?

Comment: @FredP: I didn't try. But I found a really awesome project with a similar type. Have a look at this: https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_OctoWS2811.html